# creating an index on mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have to create a mysql database to store values as below:

```
id bigint(18) auto_increment, 
NameOfStudent char(40), 
UnixTime_YearOfExam bigint(18), 
percentageScored decimal(5,2),
marksSubJect1 decimal(5,2),
marksSubJect2 decimal(5,2),
marksSubJect3 decimal(5,2),
```

The queries will be:

```
Select * 
from table 
where NameOfStudent='xyz' 
order by UnixTime_YearOfExam desc, percentageScored desc limit 3
```

There are about 2000 students with records of different years for each student. Thus each student has approx 5-10 records.
My question is:

1. What should be the index on this table so the above query is fast. The where clause and sorting as well
2. How can I select the last 3 records of each student (order by YearOfExam desc limit 3) without having to run individual queries for each student?
   so that the result of that one query will look like:

   ```
   student_1, yearOfExam2015, percentageScored
   student_1, yearOfExam2014, percentageScored
   student_1, yearOfExam2013, percentageScored
   student_2, yearOfExam2015, percentageScored
   student_2, yearOfExam2014, percentageScored
   student_2, yearOfExam2013, percentageScored
   and so on
   ```

Comment: Maybe split the data into at least two tables, one for the student, and one for the exams which only as an FK to a student. Don't worry about performance at 2k entries, it's insignificant at this point.

Comment: The total students are about 2k. The records are 5-10 per student. Total about 100k-200k

Comment: if you do the math, `2k * 10` is 20k max...

Comment: And why do you store the unix timestamp just for the year of the exam? Would a `date` field be more appropriate? or juste a int(4) since you want the year?

Comment: Also why have ids that can go up to about 1,2 billion times the (approximate) population of the earth?

Comment: Right, it's about 20K, not 200k. My mistake. The unixtime is used later to display the full dates like ( 29 May, 2012 8:00:00am / 01:00:00pm etc ). I actually don't need id bigint. The id INT will do. It's only an example. I haven't created the database. I have records in a text file which need to go in a database. The number of students will keep growing, and there are divisions in the school. The 2k is for one division. If I divide the tables into 2 parts (studentNames and marks separated) as suggested above, then what should be the index on the second table where I store marks?

Comment: The index of the exams table is also auto incremented ids. To store timestamp, use a timestamp field which is made for this exact purpose, being sorted on, and retrieved to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would index the "marks" table with "marks_id" field which auto increments. As long as you have "student_name" or "student_id" fields in both tables, you can perform an INNER JOIN to get all the info you need in one query.

Comment: okay so if I create tables like: marksID, studentID, yearOfExam, Percentage, etc and another table like: studentID, studentName etc then what will be the query to select last 3 records of every student sorted by yearOfExam? There can be more than 3 records for each student